# is it possible to attach the certificate without store in trust store in sslcontext

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

is it possible to attach the certificate without store in trust store in sslcontext

This is my code while running my code its not x509 format exception i am getting

```
@Bean(name="custRest")
    @Primary
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("C:\\test\\test.der"), password,
                        new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: you should put cert file in /resources directory, then use 'classpath:test.der' to access. so the file will be packaged into your jar and run it anywhere.

Comment: cert is creating via program

Comment: loadTrustMaterial can load crt from URL. Put cert in a place of a server then access it remotely. In server, you can use nginx as proxy to provide access service.

Comment: do you any sample code to nginx ?

Comment: wait a while, I put a sample in answer

Comment: I am able attach the certificate loadTrustMaterial  , but not able get the certificate in server side

Comment: I give a sample that I used before. wish it helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

how to config in conf\nginx.conf of nginx.

```
server {
    listen       10000; // nginx port
    server_name  localhost;

    charset utf-8;

    location /certs/ {    
       # where your cert files to be stored in nginx server machine. I suppose it is under /data/certs.
       alias /data/certs/;
       autoindex off;
    }
}
```

url of access = http://[nginx server ip ]:10000/certs/test.cer

The below is sample of building restTemplate

```java
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


    
    // suppose your server ip is 10.0.0.1
    final static String URL = "http://10.0.0.1:10000/certs/test.cer";
    
    final static String PWD = "123456";

    private RestTemplate sslTemplate() throws Exception {
        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(new URL(URL), PWD.toCharArray())
                // .loadTrustMaterial(new File(FILE_PATH), PWD.toCharArray())
                .build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

        HttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).setRetryHandler(retryHandler)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }
```